# Django What if I want to save data as the smallest type(like 1byte tinyint in mysql) with postgresql?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Good morning everyone(in Local time)

I am working with Django in Starbucks. I faced one problem and I couldn't get idea to solve it.

I am going to save data(integer type) which has range between 0~4. data is not bigger than 255 at most. When I read a manual of Django, there is SmallIntegerField which is 4 byte integer. Well, When I searched a manual of PostgreSQL, there was smallint type which is 2 byte.

But actually, my data is just less then 1byte. So I wanted to use tinyint type which has range between 0 and 255.(When I used MySQL with php, I used tinyint) I feel like its wasting if i store that small data with 4byte intergertype.

I want to show statue of something.
for example, 0 is no toilet. 1 is toilet exist for handicapped people, 2 is toilet exist but not for handicapped people. If I need to have more than 3 options, I can't cover it with BooleanType. (I ran into article which says BooleanType in Django is Tinyint. I couldn't find explanation in Django manual(version 1.10) and I couldn't also find that PostgreSQL has tinyint type.

How can I solve this problem?
I wouldn't care much if I just save a few data. but I am going to save a lot of data. It doesn't seem good idea to save data which is very small with 4byte integer type at all.

Thanks for reading this. I will appreciate if you have any idea for it and give me any advice. Thanks you! I drank my coffee all~

Comment: I would strongly advise against optimizing for storage.

Comment: @Dan What does it mean? So do you think i should save this small data just with SmallIntergerField in Django? But I will save this small data a lot. Isn't it wasting my storage?

Comment: This is just three bytes per row, forget about it, not worth the toasted brain cells.

Comment: @e4c5 for one row there would be 8 or 10 each data which range between 0 and 3. and This row will be added continuously. Well, Then, Isn't there other options but a option to just use 4 byte SmallIntegerField in Django?

Comment: This sort tof approach was certainly worth it (and indeed we adapted it ) ten years back when storage was expensive and ORMs were not so developed. Even if you have 10 million rows that's only 3Mb. while modern big databases are hundreds of GB. This is a total waste of time.

Comment: @e4c5 I see.Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to you can subclass an existing field like so

```
from django.db import models, connection


class TinyIntegerField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField):
    description = "Tiny Integer Field"

    def db_type(self, connection):
        #check backend db supports tinyint
        if any(_ in connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'] for _ in ['pyodbc', 'mysql']):
            return 'tinyint'
        else:
            return 'smallint'


class Foot(models.Model):
    numberoftoes = TinyIntegerField(default=5)
```

For signed positive/negative tinyint you can inherit from `models.SmallIntegerField` although sqlsever doesn't support negative tinyint

See 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/